# PHP maximum upload file size

Tags: php

I know that we can increase and change the maximum upload file size but I need to know are there any limits for this increasing or it's just open and depended on the server.

Comment: It's defined in the php.ini file. Check this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184513/php-change-the-maximum-upload-file-size

Comment: fine I did see this before I asked but my question is what is the limits for example can I upload a file size 1GB and if yes when we can say this is the limit you can't increase more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`upload_max_filesize` cannot exceed `post_max_size` which, in turn, [must not exceed the 32 bit signed integer limit on a 32 bit system](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size) - ie 2GiB. This is larger than your 1GB example so I would say it should be fine.

You may also need to raise `memory_limit` although advice on this online is inconsistent.

I haven't tested but I think it's therefore a fair assumption that on a 64 bit system the theoretical maximum size is 2^63-1 or 8EiB (ie Quite Large).